# issues with automatic comments on swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi, power-automate-custom-connector

I'm new to swagger (openapi) and I cannot figure out why swagger automatically comments out my code. I'm creating a custom connector on microsoft's power automate.

The only way to resolve this is if I delete the description section, but I need this description section.